# Trying to set up AD on windows server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I think I managed to get the domain controller role to function as i was able to join the domain from another computer on another network. However i had to change the preferred dns to the ip address of the server or otherwise it wouldn't allow me to join. Is this normal? I'd like to be able to join the domain with whatever the dns is configured to on the client computer.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Short (and therefore imprecise) answer would be that it is normal, you must use domain DNS server. But you really should read at least [SOME](https://www.google.com/#q=active+directory+guide) documentation about active directory.